# Number files sequentially in directory

Tags: c#, io

I have a directory which has some text files. 
I'm trying to rename the files programmatically in sequential order starting from 01, 02, 03 ... 103 and so on...

I have many files in the directory, but the files are not ordered correctly. I wanted to remove its current sequence and start from 01 and so on.

Currently, I wrote this, but it's missing a few things and its not working correctly. Can you point me in the right direction?

[image]

```
    public static void NumberFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test-File", "*.txt");
        var filenames = files.Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
        int count = 1;
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            System.IO.File.Move(f, filenames[count -1].Remove(0, 2));
            string newFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(f), (count + Path.GetFileName(f)));
            System.IO.File.Move(f, newFileName);
            count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Job Complete!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Error: When I run this I have a could not find the file.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us pattern of your file names before rename. is your file name starting with number? is it separated by `.`?

Comment: Yes the pattern follows: ##. and ###. (ex. 01. goes on till hundreds 101.) @PrasadTelkikar

Comment: unfortunately this "but it's missing a few things and its not working correctly" doesn't mean anything. How is it not working correctly, what does good and bad look like. What is missing?

Comment: `Remove(0, 2)` but actually some files contains 3 digits at the beginning and 3 symbols at the end

Comment: I would like to find the first 2 or 3 digits from the beginning essentially, remove it, then add the correct number starting from 01 on the files

Comment: You get your `FileNotFoundException` because you already moved your file before (2 lines above) here: `System.IO.File.Move(f, filenames[count -1].Remove(0, 2));` -> file f doens't exist anymore

Comment: Do you want the resulting order to be random, the same order as before or some other order(i.e. creation date)? Please also add some examples with before and after

Comment: The order should be name of the files. In order to do that the numbering of files should start with 01, 02, 03 - @Chrᴉz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we should get the files to be renamed. I doubt if *all* *.txt files should be move, probably, we should use some *pattern*:

```
string pattern = @"^[0-9]{1,3}\..*Copy \([A-Z0-9]+\)$";
```

So we can put

```
var files = Directory
  .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Test-File", "*.txt")
  .Where(file => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), pattern))
  .Select(file => new {
     // C:\Test-File\25.New File - Copy (A4).txt
     file  = file,                              
     // 25    
     index = int.Parse(Regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(file), @"^[0-9]+").Value),
     // New File - Copy (A4).txt
     name  = Path
       .GetFileName(file)
       .Substring(Regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(file), @"^[0-9]+\.").Value.Length)  
       .Trim()  
   }) 
  .OrderBy(item => item.index)
  .Select((item, i) => new {
     // C:\Test-File\25.New File - Copy (A4).txt
     oldFile = item.file,
     // C:\Test-File\07.New File - Copy (A4).txt 
     newFile = Path.Combine(
         Path.GetDirectoryName(item.file),
       $"{i + 1:d2}.{item.name}") 
   })
  .ToArray();
```

In case we want to have a look on what's going on:

```
foreach (var record in files)
  Console.WriteLine($"{record.oldFile} -> {record.newFile}");
```

Finally, loop and move:

```
foreach (var record in files)  
  File.Move(record.oldFile, record.newFile);

Console.WriteLine("Job Complete!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your digits are separated by `.`.

You can split file name by `'.'`. Skip first record and then update your file name with count.

Something like,

```
//Instead of .Remove() use below logic
System.IO.File.Move(f, string.Join(".", filenames[count -1].Split('.').Skip(1)));
```